# How to use a sed one-liner to parse "rec:id=1&name=zz&age=21" into "1 zz 21"?

Tags: sed

I can chain multiple sed substitutions and a awk operation to achieve this, but is there a single sed substitution that can do it?

Also is there any other tool that is more suitable for this parsing task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
sed -r 's!rec:id=(.*?)&name=(.*?)&age=(.*?)!\1 \2 \3!' input_file
```

If you don't know the `rec:id` etc in advance but you know there's three, you could try:

```
sed -r 's![^=]+=(.*?)&[^=]+=(.*?)&[^=]+=(.*?)!\1 \2 \3!' input_file
```

If you don't know how many `&name=value` pairs you're after in advance but want to output all the values, you could try something like:

```
grep -P -o '(?<==)([^&]*)(?=&|$)' | xargs
```

where the `-P` means 'perl regex', the regex says "find the string followed by an `&` (or end of string) and preceded by and equals sign", the `-o` means to print just the matches (ie the 1, zz, and 21) each on their own line, and the `| xargs` moves these from their own line to one line and space separated (ie `1\nzz\n21` to `1 zz 21`).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo "rec:id=1&name=zz&age=21" | sed 's/[^=]*=\([^&]*\)/\1 /g'
1 zz 21
```

However this leaves an extra space at the end, to solve this use:

```
echo "rec:id=1&name=zz&age=21"|sed 's/[^=]*=\([^&]*\)/\1 /g:;s/ $//'
1 zz 21
```

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing the values directly into variables?

```
inbound="rec:id=1&name=zz&age=21"     
eval $(echo $inbound | cut -c5- | tr \& "\n")
echo "Name:$name, ID:$id, Age:$age"
```

Or even better, though slightly more arcane:

```
inbound="rec:id=1&name=zz&age=21"
IFS=\& eval $(cut -c5- <<< $inbound)
echo "Name:$name, ID:$id, Age:$age"
```